# Dimensions of Numpy Array changes when adding element to first array of first array in 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to Numpy I found that adding a single element in first array of first array in 3D array changes the dimensions of the array. why this happens? please help!

This array gives output of 3 for ndim

```
c = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6]],
              [[7, 8, 9],
               [10, 11, 12]]])
print(c.ndim)
>> 3
```

but this array gives output of 2 for ndim

```
c = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               [4, 5, 6]],
              [[7, 8, 9],
               [10, 11, 12]]])
>> 2
```

Why so?

Comment: Check `shape` and `dtype` as well as `ndim`.  And for small examples like this display the array itself.  You second case is an `object` dtype, which for a beginner is error.  Newer numpy versions raise a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a supplement to the accepted answer, look at the resulting arrays:

```
In [39]: c
Out[39]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
In [40]: c.shape
Out[40]: (2, 2, 3)
```

The creation of such a multidimensional numeric array is documented in `numpy` basics.  This is what `numpy` was designed to create and use.

When you add elements to the first inner list (the input to this `np.array` function is a list of lists):

```
In [41]: c = np.array([[[1, 2, 3,4,5],
    ...:                [4, 5, 6]],
    ...:               [[7, 8, 9],
    ...:                [10, 11, 12]]])
<ipython-input-41-c00712d1df0d>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an 
 ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or- 
 tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you 
 meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  c = np.array([[[1, 2, 3,4,5],
```

This warning has been added in recent `numpy` versions because too many people have done this by mistake.  If you want a numeric array, don't provide ragged inputs.  This object dtype array is created in a fallback mode since it can't create a numeric array as it did in the first case.

```
In [42]: c
Out[42]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), list([4, 5, 6])],
       [list([7, 8, 9]), list([10, 11, 12])]], dtype=object)
In [43]: c.shape
Out[43]: (2, 2)
```

This has made a (2,2) array containing python objects, which in this case are lists - the same inner lists that were in the input.

Python lists contain references to objects.  An object dtype array does the same.  Performance wise is similar to list.

The creation and use of object dtype arrays is not as well documented.  For example this intro page does not mention them at all

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html

Answer (score 3):

For the first array, the shape is (3, 3, 3), the elements are numbers. For the second array, the shape is (2, 2) and the elements are python lists. (For the second array we can't write out its shape if we treat the numbers as elements, because of the inconsistency of the list length)

Comment: Thanks brother, but please can elaborate how second array element has become python list?

Comment: @Abdul An array requires its fixed, constant shape. For a (3, 3, 3) array, `A`, we can think of its shape means `row - column - depth`. No matter what `row` and `column` were chosen, `A[row, column]` would always be 3 numbers.

Numpy is clever enough to find the "best elements" without violating the rule. If `A[0, 0]` is changed from 3-numbers to 5-numbers, then `A` would be treated like an array containing lists with varying lengths.

Comment: Thanks brother this was really helpful. Can you share materials where I can master these skills.

Comment: The [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#what-is-an-array) is 100% surely helpful if you want to be a master (I never finished it because it is boring). Since Numpy is written in C, understanding C/C++ arrays/vectors also helped a lot. Guessing sometimes helps too. Good luck man!